# Is repeatedly seeding a random number generator a reasonable hash function?

Tags: c++, c, cryptography

I wish to generate a large amount of random data, which is reproducible for a given `key`, comprising a list of numbers:

```
[a, b, c, d, e, ...]
```

Is the following a good or sensible way to get a RNG into a state to generate random data, in such a way that for each n-tuple `[a, b, c, ..., n]`, that data is uncorrelated with the output for the "adjacent" n-tuples `[a+1, b, c, ..., n]`, `[a, b+1, c, ..., n]`, etc.

```
srand(a);
srand(rand() * b);
srand(rand() * c);
...
srand(rand() * n);

# generate random data:
for (int i=0; i < 100; +i)
  printf("%d", rand());
```

I think this question boils down to the following: is `rand_hash` a good hash function for the 2-tuple `(a, b)`?

```
int rand_hash(int a, int b) { 
  srand(a); 
  srand(rand() * b); 
  return rand();
}
```

NB: I don't wish to imply that `srand` and `rand` are any particular implementation of an RNG. Assume for the sake of argument that we're using a good Mersenne Twister code.

**Edit**: If it isn't clear, by "reasonable hash function" I mean the following. In the restricted case of a 2-tuple `[a, b]`, then the output of `rand_hash` should be uniform over the range of `int`, and (typically) there should be no correlation between the magnitude in the change of `a` or `b` and the magnitude of the change in the return value.

Comment: How do you define "reasonable hash function"? What are you doing with the hash code?

Comment: `srand(a^b^c^...^n)` is faster than what you have, and just as effective.

Comment: Assume `n` is zero. Then (if `srand` completely sets the state of the generator) the output is independent of all previous blocks.

Comment: @MooingDuck No, that's useless if we're discussing tuples, because the output for a=3, b=2 should be different from a=2, b=3.

Comment: @MooingDuck: No, that's not true. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx -- scroll down to "In particular, be careful of "xor"."

Comment: @Nick: Why should those outputs be different? We're talking about a hashing function here. Duplicates are allowed. (obviously, your set of possible inputs is two times the set of possible outputs, so there's going to be overlap somewhere)

Comment: Nick: Your origional has the same issue, but I see your point.  @Billy: I've never heard that before.  Good to know.

Comment: @MooingDuck My comment was directed at the code in the question, not at your comment.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann That's a valid point. One could simply do `srand(rand() + x)` to avoid this issue, though, right?

Comment: @BillyONeal The question is tagged with [cryptography], so I assume we want a hash function where it is difficult to find duplicates. Simply XORing the inputs does not fit the bill.

Comment: @MooingDuck The code I posted is **not** symmetric over `a` and `b`.

Comment: @Nick: Yes, with `+` (or XOR or `-`) it is better. Still I would not trust this construction without knowing what `rand` and `srand` really do (or at least having some assured properties for them).

Comment: @Nick: It may be symetric for some implementation of `rand`.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: I did say "Assume for the sake of argument that we're using a good Mersenne Twister code"...

Comment: @Nick: Most C implementations of `rand` don't use algorithms as good as Mersenne Twister. You're lucky to get a good linear congruential generator. C's `rand` is not designed for serious cryptographic applications.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, this is not a reasonable approach.

1. You don't know what the implementation of `rand` is. Random number generators are designed to provide approximately uniformly distributed numbers over a period of several generated mnumbers. They are not designed to provide uniformly distributed numbers over the set of (32 bit) seeds. In your hypothetical `mersenne_twister` case, the random number generator has state much larger than the integer you supply to `srand` (specifically, `624*sizeof(int)`). Most of the power the RNG has to ensure its output is random and uniform are from that additional state, and you took that away. (The seed can be only one of 2^32 states)
2. If you ever upgrade your compiler or libraries or something similar, anything you might have serialized to disk will become unreadable. (If `rand` is a black box, nobody says that tomorrow's implementation matches today's).
3. Your hashing function's output returns the same thing for the same inputs to `srand`. Therefore, you already have a hash -- the input to `srand`. The RNG generates the same output for a given input to `srand`. Therefore the number of hashes you may obtain is no greater than just returning the hash you would have already calculated. If your initial hash into srand is of poor distribution for a hash table, then scale the hash appropriately such that it performs well in your table.
4. For some implementations of `rand`, this performs extremely poorly. Consider a [linear congruential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) generator (which is more common with C libraries because it has state of `sizeof(int)` -- e.g. [the BSD generator](http://www.google.com/codesearch#p9nGS4eQGUI/gnu/gsl/gsl-1.8.tar.gz%7C8VCQSLJ5jR8/gsl-1.8/rng/rand.c&q=rand&type=cs) ). A LCG follows the form `xNext = a*xCurrent + b`. Consider:

   ```
   static int seed = 0;

   void srand(int newSeed)
   {
       seed = newSeed;
   }

   int rand()
   {
       seed = (int) ((1103515245 * ((unsigned int)seed) + 12345) & 0x7fffffffUL); 
       return seed;
   }
   ```

   Note that this (common) type of generator produces hash values easily correlated to your input values.

Comment: I don't understand point 3. How can I combine a tuple of integers into a single argument to `srand()` in such a way that their order is important?

Comment: I don't follow point #3.  You seem to be saying that his hash is a hash, and that it works as he intends.

Comment: @Nick: multiply them by different (constant) values, like the powers of two?

Comment: @Nick: `return left ^ (right + 1)`? I'm not sure what a good hash would be for you. As always, a good hash depends on the probability distribution of your data. (And besides, that's a separate question) Consider http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=combine+hash+codes

Comment: @MooingDuck: #3 is saying that he doesn't get anything by going through the motions of rand and srand. Sure, the numbers you get are different. The distribution of the hash you get is different, of course, but going through rand doesn't make the hash any "better" in terms of "strength" of the hash (at least not in any well defined manner).

Comment: @BillyONeal: Oh, right.  Yeah, that makes sense now.  I already knew the tidbit, I just didn't understand his wording.

Comment: @BillyONeal I'm still puzzled by #3. You talk about "better" and "different" in your comment above, but better than what? Different to what? He hasn't presented an alternate hashing method, and nor have you, so I don't know what you're comparing it to.

Comment: @Nick: I don't know what his other hashing method is. He obviously got the numbers he's putting in to `srand` from somewhere though...

Comment: @BillyONeal I assumed that they're not a hash at all, but rather the actual data he's depending on.

Comment: @Nick: There's no difference. If your data is sufficiently distributed that it works as a hash, then it works as a hash. Without knowing anything about the data in use there's no way to write a hash better than just using the raw `int` as the hash.

Comment: @BillyONeal But he didn't say anything about how his input was distributed. It's also a set of integers, not a single integer.

Comment: @Nick: But each integer can be interpreted as a hash. After all, a valid RNG might return it's seed as the first number generated, and then this degenerates into int1 * int2. You can't make any arguments about the distribution of the resulting hash because A. you don't know the distribution of the input, and B. you don't know the implementation of rand. Even if you assume the most common implementation of rand (a LCG), then the output has the same distribution as the input for most input sets.

Comment: @BillyONeal Sure, you could treat each integer as a hash - but the OP specifically asked about how to seed a PRNG based on a tuple, and simply saying "each element could be treated as a hash" doesn't help there. Treating each element as a hash, too, may give very poor distribution depending on what the numbers are. And I wasn't making any argument about the distribution of a prng-based hash, just that your point 3 seems to refer to a hashing function that nobody's specified or even indicated exists.

Comment: @Nick: The point is though, running through the RNG doesn't change the distribution of the numbers. The strength of your hash is therefore no better than the numbers you put in to it.

Answer (score 2):

What about using `boost::hash_combine` http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/doc/html/hash_combine.html to create your initial seed? Using `srand` more than once always triggers red flags in my mind.

Comment: and `std::hash<int>` for the initial values.  Good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Potential problem:

What if another thread calls `rand()` in the middle of your hash function?

Comment: It's a fair point, but we can assume for the minute that threading issues aren't relevant here. In practice I'm using an instantiated RNG from C++11 `<random>`.