# Random number at fixed position

Tags: c++, random

I'm wondering how should I get a random number at a fixed position , so when I go back to that position i'll see the same random number.

First I tried something like this :

```
int getRand( int x , int y )
{ 
    srand( x * y );
    return rand();
}
```

but here -1 * -1 are the same as 1 * 1, so Ill get a lot of symmetry.

I've then tried :

```
int getRand( int x , int y )
{ 
    srand( x * ( 1 << 12 ) + y );
    return rand();
}
```

and

```
int getRand( int x , int y ) // this one gave the best result
{ 
    srand( x );
    int rand1 = rand();

    srand( y );
    int rand2 = rand();

    srand( rand1 * rand2 );
    return rand();
}
```

and

```
int getRand( int x , int y )
{ 
    srand( x );
    int rand1 = rand();

    srand( y );
    int rand2 = rand();

    srand( rand1 * ( 1 << 12 ) + rand2 );
    return rand();
}
```

So how should I do it, since none of the above give a nice result ? ( by nice I mean random , it all looks repetitive )

Comment: You don't want a random number, you want a hash function.

Comment: You might be right, but can you be more explicit? The code above should generate heights for a map.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the result? That is, why do you need a random number? Do you have more precise acceptability criteria?

Comment: You should look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933473/is-repeatedly-seeding-a-random-number-generator-a-reasonable-hash-function)

Comment: @PangratieAndrei If you are trying to get random height values for a map, you should simply store the generated numbers in a (2d) vector. In that case you don't actually want a hash function as your code seemed to indicate.

Comment: I agree with @Nabla your use case seems to be served better by seeding a PRNG once (`rand` is not necessarily the best option though) and taking `width * height` values from it, assigning them to the map positions in some order. But you could also use a hash function (hashing two ints into one).

Comment: My problem is that I need to go back any time to that specific part of the map and it should be the same. I'm actually calculating heights for a specific part in the map.

Comment: I‘m currently out of time for a fully fledged answer, but you definetly should look into noise algorithms such as *Perlin Noise* (ask your favourite search engine about it).

Comment: You say, "C++" -- can you use C++11? There's a new random number generation library in C++11, so answers for C++03 would be rather different (or would just refer you to a Boost equivalent of the new C++11 functionality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you want to avoid `srand` and `rand`. They modify global state and so (as one possible problem) your code isn't thread-safe. Also they aren't guaranteed to produce very high-quality random data, and in many common implementations they don't.

Based on what you're doing with `rand`, it looks to me like what you actually want is a "random-looking" hash function, that is to say there's no obvious relation between `getRand(x,y)` and `getRand(x+1,y)`, `getRand(x,y+1)`, `getRand(x+1, y-1)`, or any other obvious correlation between output and input.

Anyway hash functions on integers for use with hashtables *are not suitable*. Frequently these are just the identify function. Additional hashes used for multiple hashing often use some prime number stride or something, so still are not random-looking.

If you have no performance concerns, then the best available hash functions are "cryptographically secure" hashes. MD5 would be more than good enough for this purpose -- it's too weak for general modern cryptographic use, but it's very random-looking. So for example you could define `getRand(x,y)` to be the last 4 bytes of MD5 hash of the 8-byte sequence consisting of the 4 bytes of `x` followed by the 4 bytes of `y`.

Unfortunately, secure hashes are slow. If what you need is a very fast and *somewhat* random-looking function, then something like [FNV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler-Noll-Vo_hash_function) might do, and perhaps fold the upper and lower bits and/or multiply the result (in an unsigned type) by a large prime in order to mix up the bits somewhat. But look at the results carefully because this is *not* its intended purpose.

---

If a secure hash is too slow and you still want some kind of quality control, then you can improve things using a PRNG based on your typical access pattern. This doesn't help you at all if your typical access to the data is unpredictable.

But for example if you mainly access vertical lines in sequence (constant `x` value, incrementing `y` value) then you might do something like this:

```
uint32_t getRand(uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
    std::mt19937 rng;
    rng.seed(good_hash(x, y / 4096));
    y = y % 4096;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<uint32_t> dst;
    while (y-- > 0) {
        dst(rng);
    }
    return dst(rng);
}
```

`good_hash` needs to be a vaguely decent hash function, because although the sequence output by Mersenne Twister is very random-looking, the relation between seeds and first outputs isn't.

I have used `mt19937` (a Mersenne Twister) because it's generally random enough for simulation, and it's faster than stream generators that are cryptographically secure.

Seeding the `rng` is expensive relative to generating one output from it, so you can now provide another function for sequential access that is much more efficient since it can return 4096 values between reseeds.

If you have a typical access that's something other than vertical lines then adjust the technique accordingly. For example if you access mostly one local region of the map at a time, then:

- divide your map up into smaller squares, let's say 1024 * 1024 pixels
- seed the RNG using the index of the smaller square, that is to say the most significant bits of `x` and `y`
- run the RNG for 1024*1024 outputs to generate all the random values for a small square, and store these for as long as you are accessing that region. I suppose you'd want to be able to cache 4 small squares at a time, to process regions that overlap the corners of the small squares. That would only require 16MB.

Btw this is (very roughly speaking) how file-system-level encryption is typically optimized to allow efficient seeking within files: the filesystem can decrypt one block at a time without an expensive computation per byte. And just like any filesystem it will generally cache any block it looks at, so that other nearby accesses will be fast. Of course crypto doesn't use Mersenne Twister, which is not sufficiently secure. I believe it must also use a good hash to choose the seed -- for example it might use a secure hash function to combine a random file key (`x`) with the offset of the block (`y / 4069`).

Answer (score 0):

Thats not a pseudo-random number generator, its a hash function.

A hash function is a function with this (*ideal*) properties:

- Is injective, that is, each input value has a output (result) defined.
- That result is unique for the value, no other input results in that output (Ideally).

So a hash function could be viewed as a function which identifies a result with an input.

There are a lot of reference on the internet about the topic of wirtting a good hash function. However, since C++11 and the addition of `std::unordered_map` container (Which is a hash map), the `<functional>` header includes a function `std::hash()` which is overloaded for most of the common types.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong here, but I will go on the questioner's comment.

If you are trying to get random height values for a map, you should simply store the generated numbers in a (2d) vector. In that case you don't actually want a hash function as your code seemed to indicate.

For example like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    std::srand(std::time(NULL));
    int size_x = 100;
    int size_y = 100;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> heights(size_x, std::vector<int>(size_y));
    for(int i=0; i<size_x; ++i)
        for(int j=0; j<size_y; ++j)
            heights[i][j] = std::rand();
}
```

Note however that my chosen seed and the random number generator are bad. If you can you should use the random module introduced in c++11: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/

Comment: No, I cant use this. I'm making a procedural map so ill need the same value of the height when I return.

Comment: @PangratieAndrei Since you already generated all heights in the beginning your function simply has to return from the vector.

Comment: my map should be something like 1024 X 1024 Km^2 or bigger with 1 m detail so I cant store it.

Comment: Random number generators are designed to give highly unpredictable output and in general they do not need to be reversible, so you cannot use random number generators for this then. Also do you actually want random independent heights or should there be some structure in them?

Comment: Random independent heights for testing. I want to use Diamond Square Algorithm after I figure out how to get really random numbers because I need random numbers for the algorithm to look good.

Comment: In that case a hash function would be appropriate. Try `std::hash` or if that is not random enough, implement one of the many typical algorithms you can easily find. If you want different values for each run you might add a constant random number to all hash calls.

Comment: `std::hash<int>` is very likely to be the identity function.